# Add Encript Password zip backup Mysql

Tags: mysql, passwords

I want to give the password in the file, how I do it. My example script

```
    @echo off
    :: make sure to change the settings from line 4-9
    set dbUser=root
    set dbPassword=root
    set port=3306
    set backupDir="D:\data"
    set mysqldump="C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe"
    set mysqlDataDir="C:\xampp\mysql\data"
    set zip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    :: get date
    for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (
        set mm=%%i
        set dd=%%j
        set yy=%%k
    )
    if %mm%==01 set Month="Jan"
    if %mm%==02 set Month="Feb"
    if %mm%==03 set Month="Mar"
    if %mm%==04 set Month="Apr"
    if %mm%==05 set Month="May"
    if %mm%==06 set Month="Jun"
    if %mm%==07 set Month="Jul"
    if %mm%==08 set Month="Aug"
    if %mm%==09 set Month="Sep"
    if %mm%==10 set Month="Oct"
    if %mm%==11 set Month="Nov"
    if %mm%==12 set Month="Dec"
    set dirName=%dd%_%Month%_%yy%
    set fileSuffix=%dd%-%Month%-%yy%
    :: remove echo here if you like
    echo "dirName"="%dirName%"

    :: switch to the "data" folder
    pushd "%mysqlDataDir%"
    :: create backup folder if it doesn't exist
    if not exist %backupDir%\%dirName%\   mkdir %backupDir%\%dirName%
    :: iterate over the folder structure in the "data" folder to get the databases
    for /d %%f in (*) do (
        :: remove echo here if you like
        echo processing folder "%%f"
        %mysqldump% --host="localhost" --user=%dbUser% --password=%dbPassword% --port=%port% --single-transaction --add-drop-table --databases %%f > %backupDir%\%dirName%\%%f.sql
        %zip% a -tzip %backupDir%\%dirName%\%fileSuffix%_%%f . sql  gz %backupDir%\%dirName%\%%f.sql`enter code here`
        del %backupDir%\%dirName%\%%f .sql
    )
    popd
```

Comment: I know that `-P` or `--password` allows you to encrypt a zip with a given password, rather than prompting you for a password from stdin, but I don't know enough about MySQL to give an example using -P. Also, zip encryption is trivial to crack, don't think it matters in this case, just fyi. Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip